# interpret the histogram (generated in excel)

Tags: normal-distribution

I have generated and attached the histogram here for reference. On X-axis it's time in hour[image]

- Considering, mean=7.52, SD=1.71, upper bound =7.76, lower bound=7.28, confidence interval=96% - What is the interpretation of this graph ?

Can I predict it is a normal distribution? .

Answer (score 0):

Well, since the sample size is greater than 30 (CLT), and it is relatively symmetric, cause it is obviously not the population SD, technically yes. I would do a box plot to check for symmetry. And what do you mean by interpretation?

Comment: If you see 11.77 in graph it's empty , we been taught that there shouldn't be any empty bins...As it is generated in excel I am just puzzled if it's right...Also can I say looking at the graph that as it's left skewed more of the values there in 95% chance that it will be at left hand side ?

Comment: I have not heard the empty bin condition before, but it definetly makes sense as a condition. From looking at it, it looks like a poor approximation of a normal distribution. You could try doing a higher sample size or increasing the number of bins. Is this data that is generated by excel that's suppose to be normal? Also I am not sure what your second question is about skewness, could you rephrase it?

Comment: I had set of observation so to check if it's a normal distribution I plotted histogram ...expecting a bell shape curve...Regarding second point may be I am trying to interpret the left skewness of the graph. If a graph is left skewed then what explanation am I suppose to give

Comment: Well, regarding the left-skewness, it depends on where you want to make the cutoff between relatively symmetric and too skewed to be considered normal. I would say it's pretty skewed, so a normal distribution is probably not a great approximation. I have had data that when increasing the number of bins has helped see the more of what the distribution is. But this is probably not the case with this data. If it isn't normal then you can explain the distribution by shape, center, spread one of these factors being skewed-left. You can perform statistical normality tests for further assuranse.